# Updating matlab plot with two series

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to have an updating plot that plots two series. The first series is continous and the second only occurs ever month.

So far I have the following series:

`y`: daily data

`ymp`: daily data with NaN except for the first day of the month.

I want to plot `y` and `ymp` in one graph were `y` is a line and `ymp` is only a dot.

Now I can do this as follows:

```
    hold on
    plot(dp, y);
    plot(dp, ymp, 'o'); 
    datetick;
    hold off
```

The problem is that after updating the plot simply adds more lines on top of the plot instead of resetting the old one. How can this be changed in a more efficient way? That I simply replace the content of the figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [refresh](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refresh.html) or [enter link description here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refreshdata.html), but the best option is probably 
`set(dp,'XData',y,'YData');`

Something like:

```
hold on
plot(dp, y);
plot(dp, ymp, 'o'); 
datetick;
hold off
y = new_y
set(dp,'dp',y,'y_new');
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the 'hold on' between the two series. You are simply doing a hold off followed by a hold on. this will have no effect.

```
plot series1
hold on
plot series2
hold off
```

Comment: This way the plot series1 will always be drawn fresh because it comes after the hold off.